# in Gwt, there are 2 different packages (or 2 options) for doing drag n Drop? Which one is better?

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I know very little about Drag n Drop in Gwt. I searched on internet & it seems that there are 2 different packages (or 2 options) for doing drag n Drop.
https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

&

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/source/browse/DragDrop/

Why Google developed 2 different strategies for DnD? Which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GWT drag&drop implementation is based on the [HTML5 D&D API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/). Such API basically allows you to transfer *data* using native drag&drop. That means you can, for instance, drag things from outside the browser. Simplifing, you need to setup a drag element, a drop target and the `DataTransfer` object which will hold the actual data to transfer. I guess it can also be used to simulate drag&drop of `DOM` elements (say, widgets) within an app by creating&destroying (on `dragstart` and on `dragend`), but its purpose is different.

Since this API is rather new, not every browser natively support it. See http://caniuse.com/dragndrop. See also this [video](http://youtu.be/KEkR1ox_K10?t=20m37s) along with its [presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/gwt_html5_a_web_develops_dream.pdf) to get you started.

On the other side [gwt-dnd](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) was meant to really drag&drop widgets within an application. So you can, out of the box, move things around. Also, this library is not developed directly by Google (although its author work/ed for the company). See its [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/wiki/GettingStarted#Adding_gwt-dnd_to_an_%28Eclipse%29_GWT_Project) and [showcase](https://gwt-dnd.appspot.com).

Another relatively recent library, is the drag&drop [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers) for [GwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/). GwtQuery is a jQuery-like library for GWT, and its d&d support is via the previous plugin. It also support d&d between cell widgets. See its [showcase](http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/branches/droppable_1_0/demo/ContactCellSample/ContactCellSample.html). Also in this case, such library is meant to provide d&d capabilities to native GWT widgets.

Comment: thax u very much for ur info!