# How to move widgets dynamically in GWT FlowPanel?

Tags: gwt

I'm adding widgets dynamically to a FlowPanel in a specific order (by date acuatlly), but sometimes i need to position a widget before or after another one. Is there a way to do that in GWT? I thought about using gwt-dnd but i'd rather give it a try with the current API if it's possible.
PS: I'm using GWT2.4.

Comment: You mean by drag&drop or programmatically?

Comment: Any of the methods would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically you can use one of the `insert()` methods of the `FlowPanel`.

Alternatively you can use native drag&drop or any other library that leverage drag&drop functionality. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250178/in-gwt-there-are-2-different-packages-or-2-options-for-doing-drag-n-drop-whi) for more informations.