# Are there any documentation on DnD in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have failed to find any documentation on how to implement drag and drop in the Google Web Toolkit. The [official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) page does not even mention it (besides on a reference to a HTML5-feature page that does not, itself, mention anything about drag and drop. Can anyone point me to some official documentation on how to actually do it in GWT?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250178/in-gwt-there-are-2-different-packages-or-2-options-for-doing-drag-n-drop-whi/16252380#16252380).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://jamies-gwt.blogspot.de/2012/11/gwt24-drag-drop-in-tree.html

The trip is done by:
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DragStartHandler.html